# Why will regex "([a-z])((?!\\1)[a-z])" match string "aa" in C++11?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Indeed running

```
regex pattern("([a-z])((?!\\1)[a-z])");
cout << regex_match("aa", pattern) << endl;
```

results in the output "1", yet the first group matched is "a", and if instead I run

```
regex pattern("([a-z])((?!a)[a-z])");
cout << regex_match("aa", pattern) << endl;
```

I get "0" as expected.

Note that exactly the same regex works as expected in Python 3, i.e. running

```
re.match("([a-z])((?!\\1)[a-z])", "aa")
```

produces no matches. Can someone explain what is happening here?

Just for reference, I am using g++ (tdm64-1) 5.1.0 with flags -O2 and -std=c++11.

Comment: shows 1 for all languages [here](https://regex101.com/r/nUvaOA/1)

Comment: @NathanOliver you should only use single backslashes when working with regex101

Comment: @SebastianProske Well look at that.  Thanks for the info.  TIL.

Comment: This appears to be a bug for gcc 5.X.  It compiles with 6.2 and on clang 3.8.0 and produces 0.

Comment: regex from libstdc++ seems to be buggy, I would try boost one until sure it works

Comment: So, the question is, should that regular expression produce the same result as `a[0] != a[1] && a[0] == a[2]`? Seems like a rather convoluted way of writing something that's quite straightforward in ordinary code.

Comment: @PeteBecker I think the main point this question exposes is that libstdc++'s regex implementation is broken in this version. OP just did a good job of providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it was bugged in GCC5.
It works as expected in [GCC6](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/265a9b2880a7dea4) and [MSVC14](http://rextester.com/COD75511).